# remote submit new post to blog by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

i use this Ajax post code for submit post to my blog in blogsky blog hosting .

```
var result = null;
var scriptUrl = "http://www.blogsky.com/cp/weblog/post.bs";

    $.ajax({    
         url: scriptUrl,
         type: 'post',
         data: ({txtTitle : 'BEHZAD', txtText : 'BEHZAD' , hidAction : 'Publish'}),
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
            },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           document.write(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
           }
         });
```

and blog page cotain this form . and blog hosting is not for mine and i cant change sending post code .

```
<form action="http://www.blogsky.com/cp/weblog/post.bs" method="post">
        <table id="frmposttb">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="txtTitle" value="" style="width:320px;" maxlength="64" onkeypress="FKeyPress(event)" onkeydown="FKeyDown(event)" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="editor">
                    <textarea id="txtText" name="txtText" rows="1" cols="1" style="width: 545px; height: 290px"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidAction" value="Publish" />
                <td class="tdl"><input type="submit" value="SEND"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

but when load page get this erorr

parsererror - Error: jQuery18203252281643505811_1367758980965 was not called

and page roload and reload . i use other dataType but still error

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
dataType: 'sonp'
dataType: 'html'
dataType: '....'
```

Comment: Have you contacted support and asked them about the problem?

Comment: yes dont answer my question

Comment: well what did you ask them and what they wrote back? Please add this important information to your question to have it in the right context.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line from your `$.ajax()` call:

```
 jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
```

Also, you cannot use a `jsonp` datatype with a synchronous call `async: false`, as stated in jquery `$.ajax()` docs:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

So use `async: true,` instead.

Comment: still same erorr | parsererror - Error: jQuery18206470861525416229_1367760679727 was not called |

Comment: Maybe your server does not support jsonp , try using plain json or html datatypes.

Comment: i use all of type but get back error . is possible blog hosting off all ajax submit post?